# Strange Nginx Issue

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, php-fpm

We are facing a strange issue on our servers. We have servers with 1GB RAM and some drupal sites are running on it.

Generally all sites are loading fine but sometimes we are unable to access any sites. After waiting for 10mts we are getting a 502 gateway timeout error. In middle when we restart either nginx or php5-fpm it will load.

Our configurations are as follows:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 400000;

events {
        worker_connections 10000;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}

http {

        access_log      off;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 2;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;
        keepalive_requests 100000;
        reset_timedout_connection on;
        port_in_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        proxy_connect_timeout  600s;
        proxy_send_timeout  600s;
        proxy_read_timeout  600s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
       open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
       open_file_cache_valid 30s;
       open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
       open_file_cache_errors on;
```

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
;pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
;pm.max_requests = 200
request_terminate_timeout = 300s
```

And please see the added contents in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
fs.file-max = 150000
net.core.netdev_max_backlog=32768
net.core.optmem_max=20480
#net.core.rmem_default=65536
#net.core.rmem_max=16777216
net.core.somaxconn=50000
#net.core.wmem_default=65536
#net.core.wmem_max=16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=120
#net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=30
#net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3
#net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=120
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans=262144
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=524288
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets=524288
#net.ipv4.tcp_mem=1048576 1048576 2097152
#net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save=1
net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries=0
#net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=4096 16384 16777216
#net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries=2
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
#net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=2
#net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=4096 32768 16777216
```

There is no errors getting on log entries. Can anyone please help us on it.

Thanks

Comment: Try disabling keepalive

Comment: But it will depreciate performance right?

Comment: You're running Drupal with a limit of 5 PHP processes and wondering why it locks up? (hint: allow a *lot* more php processes and uncomment both the idle timeout and the max requests)

Comment: ....and try running with N nginx process (where N=number of cpus +1)